Xichang is a spaceport

Solve on Penpa+
Across
5. Experience great pleasure from eating half of quiche after Northern surrender (10)
6. Ex of Aniston's is constant target on vacation (4)
8. Executed Argentine staying behind amicable façade for long (4)
9. Extreme situation with "tablet generation" puts a stop to compassion (9)
11/24. Xi's development venture in Tibet: An alive android (it moves!) (4,3,4,10)
14. Exiting R&B singer's hotel: A drug addict (4)
15. Extravagant Tory welcomes right-winger that's boisterous in the UK (5)
16. Exiled writer ignoring onset of serious disease (4)
17. Xichang-launched orbiter is tracking celebrity's legal acts sometimes associated with marriage (4,7)
19. Excitable and generous old drunk (9)
21. Extemporaneously perform, in Basie's style, all but intro (4)
23. X-wing pilot's uncle is in the red, accordin' to hearsay (4)
24. (See 11 across)
Down
1. Extra huge rock rolled on top of Achilles (4)
2. X-ray visionary and Wisconsin writer Hubbard assume command post, accompanied by Turkey's #1 general (7,7)
3. Xmas predecessor you'll see regularly (4)
4. Xerxes' unimpressive victory: Composing earthly poem (11)
6. Exercising, old ugly patient gets to profess innocence (5,3,6)
7. Excess skin removal for guy in Sherwood (4)
10. Experiencing attraction regardless of gender, Caligula perhaps pursues Paulina, at first in playful behaviour (11)
11. Executive in fashion house (4)
12. .XLS's sister format contains headers for rows and indicators for order of columns (5)
13. "X", for Musk, is suddenly not all that? (4)
18. Extract picture (4)
20. Extraterrestrial visits quiet man whose brother was murdered (4)
22. Expend five euros to support soldier (4)

Solutions to clues:
Across

5. RELINQUISH | RELISH eating (N QUI) | Experience great pleasure from eating half of quiche after Northern surrender (10)
6. PITT | PI + T(-arge)T | Ex of Aniston's is constant target on vacation (4)
8. ACHE | CHE behind A(-micable) | Executed Argentine staying behind amicable façade for long (4)
9. EMERGENCY | E + GEN in MERCY | Extreme situation with "tablet generation" puts a stop to compassion (9)
11/24. BELT AND ROAD INITIATIVE | (TIBET AN ALIVE ANDROID IT)* | Xi's development venture in Tibet: An alive android (it moves!) (4,3,4,10)
14. USER | US(-h)ER | Exiting R&B singer's hotel: A drug addict (4)
15. RORTY | TORY* welcomes R | Extravagant Tory welcomes right-winger that's boisterous in the UK (5)
16. OVID | (-c)OVID | Exiled writer ignoring onset of serious disease (4)
17. NAME CHANGES | (CHANG'E 'S) after NAME | Xichang-launched orbiter is tracking celebrity's legal acts sometimes associated with marriage (4,7)
19. EROGENOUS | (GENEROUS O)* | Excitable and generous old drunk (9)
21. WING | (-s)WING | Extemporaneously perform, in Basie's style, all but intro (4)
23. OWEN | homophone of OWIN' | X-wing pilot's uncle is in the red, accordin' to hearsay (4)
24. (See 11 across)

Down

1. MEGA | GEM< on A(-chilles) | Extra huge rock rolled on top of Achilles (4)
2. WILHELM RONTGEN | | WI L.RON containing HELM, plus T + GEN | X-ray visionary and Wisconsin writer Hubbard assume command post, accompanied by Turkey's #1 general (7,7)
3. YULE | YoUlLsEe | Xmas predecessor you'll see regularly (4)
4. THERMOPYLAE | (EARTHLY POEM)* | Xerxes' unimpressive victory: Composing earthly poem (11)
6. PLEAD NOT GUILTY | (OLD UGLY PATIENT)* | Exercising, old ugly patient gets to profess innocence (5,3,6)
7. TUCK | ddef | Excess skin removal  guy in Sherwood (4)
10. PANROMANTIC | ROMAN pursues P in ANTIC (though surely it's only ROMAN that's inside ANTIC?) | Experiencing attraction regardless of gender, Caligula perhaps pursues Paulina, at first in playful behaviour (11)
11. BOSS | ddef | Executive  fashion house (4)
12. DORIC | DOC contains R(-ows) I(-indicators) | .XLS's sister format contains headers for rows and indicators for order of columns (5)
13. KISS | substring | "X", for Musk, is suddenly not all that? (4)
18. DRAW | ddef | Extract <> picture (4)
20. SETH | ET visits SH | Extraterrestrial visits quiet man whose brother was murdered (4)
22. GIVE | GI + V + E | Expend five euros to support soldier (4)

Filled grid:

 


I believe the issue you have is a typo in 2D; when you fix that, 14A is "US(-h)ER".

yes, I had noticed the same and was just in the process of fixing it when you posted that :-).

(Given how quickly you posted that, I'm guessing that you had a nearly-complete solution. Sorry!)

Incidentally, congratulations to Jafe on a truly ex-cessive X-word.
